# SQL - Running Calcuation on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table with two columns called 'AllocationTimestamp' and 'DeallocationTimestamp' and a column called 'UserId'

Many users can be allocated at a given time but once the first user is allocated the session starts and when their is no user allocated the session ends.

Example would be:

```
User1: 2016-01-01 -> 2016-01-05
User2: 2016-01-02 -> 2016-01-10
User1: 2016-01-07 -> 2016-01-15
User3: 2016-01-03 -> 2016-01-08

User1: 2016-01-20 -> 2016-01-22
User2: 2016-01-20 -> 2016-01-25
User1: 2016-01-25 -> 2016-01-28
```

This should give two sessions where one starts at 2016-01-01 and ends at 2016-01-15 and the other starts at 2016-01-20 and ends at 2016-01-28

Please note that when a user has not been deallocated the 'DeallocatedTimestamp' is null.

Could someone help me to put some SQL together to get a list of sessions with start and end dates?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called Sessions, this script might give you a starting point...

```
with BaseData as
(
    select *
        , row_number() over(order by AllocationTimestamp asc) as SeqNo
    from Sessions
)
,Data(UserID, AllocationTimestamp, DeallocationTimestamp, SeqNo, SessionNo) as
(
    select BD.*
        , 1
    from BaseData as BD
    where (BD.AllocationTimestamp=(select min(AllocationTimestamp) from Sessions))

    union all

    select BD.*
        , D.SessionNo + case when (BD.AllocationTimestamp between D.AllocationTimestamp and coalesce(D.DeallocationTimestamp,current_timestamp)) then 0 else 1 end
    from BaseData as BD
    join Data as D
        on(BD.SeqNo-1=D.SeqNo)

)

select SessionNo
    ,min(AllocationTimestamp)
    ,case when max(coalesce(DeallocationTimestamp,current_timestamp))=current_timestamp then null else max(DeallocationTimestamp) end
from Data
group by SessionNo
```

Comment: Thanks you very much